# swift default string interpolation for object

Tags: swift

I've made an class - call it Blah.  It contains a string "value".   So anytime someone makes a string out of it - I want it to appear as the value.  So I try it:

```swift
let x = Blah( "hello world")
XCTAassertEqual("hello world", "\(x)")
```

out of the box - of course it doesn't work - I haven't told it how to do the rendering.  So I do some googling and find that thing is "description" - so add this to Blah:

```swift
public var description = {get{return _value}}
```

and then the test becomes this:

```swift
let x = Blah( "hello world")
XCTAassertEqual("hello world", "\(x.description)")
XCTAassertEqual("hello world", "\(x)")
```

the first assert works, but the second is still giving me the whole object

so - more googling - I find that you can add custom string interpolations.. so I add this:

```swift
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: Blah) {
        appendLiteral( value.description)
    }
}
```

and that achieves... well... absolutely nothing.
How do I change the way my objects are represented by string interpolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `description` you have seen belongs to the protocol [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) and is used when you want to convert an object to a string representation. So all you need to do is to conform to the protocol and `description` will be used in your tests

```
struct Blah: CustomStringConvertible {
    let value: String

    init(_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    var description: String {
        value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it to work.

```
class Blah {
    let value: String
    init(_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: Blah) {
        appendLiteral(value.value)
    }
}

func testBlah() {
    let blah = Blah("Hello world")
    XCTAssertEqual("Hello world", "\(blah)")
}
```

The test passes.

Answer (score 0):

You were right about `var description`. However, you forgot to add the protocol `CustomStringConvertible`:

```
struct Blah {
    let value: String
}

extension Blah: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { value }
}

let x = Blah(value: "Hello world")
print("Hello world: ", "\(x)")
```

Without the protocol, `description` is just a custom property.